# Offline Google Analytics for PWA

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-analytics, progressive-web-apps, offline

I tried to follow the official tutorial at https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/integrating-analytics#offline_analytics for my Angular App.

But, the document looks like old. Because when I installed sw-offline-google-analytics by npm. There were not offline-google-analytics-import.js in node_modules.

So I copied the sw-offline-google-analytics.prod.v0.0.25.js in node_modules to my src directory. And I did what I can everything as much as I understood like below. There was any compile errors. But when I tested like https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/integrating-analytics#swjs_4, it doesn’t work.

[In app.module.ts]

```
imports: [
    ServiceWorkerModule.register(‘combined-sw.js’, { enabled: environment.production })
]
```

[In combined-sw.js]

```
importScripts(‘ngsw-worker.js’);
importScripts(‘firebase-messaging-sw.js’);
importScripts(‘sw-offline-google-analytics.prod.v0.0.25.js’);
goog.offlineGoogleAnalytics.initialize();
```

[In angular.json]

```
“assets”: [

    “src/sw-offline-google-analytics.prod.v0.0.25.js”

]
```

Could you help me to solve this issue? I cannot find any hints in googling.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [`workbox-google-analytics`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-google-analytics) instead.

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize();
```